# How to calculate the mean of consecutive datapoints in a column of data without looping

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, for-loop, mean

I tried to calculate the average/mean of consecutive data points `(ith and i+1th entries)` in a column of data using `For` loop through the column indices, unfortunately, I was stuck and the only for the loop to be successful is by subtracting the last index. Question is, is there any `Pandas` or `Numpy` way to calculate this average through the entire index without the `For` loop (takes time!) and without necessarily subtracting the last index?

Here's my attempt so far, using an extract from my larger dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('class_data.dat',sep='\t')
df
```

```
    Age     BMI     Gender
0   23.0    17.2    Male
1   25.6    16.3    Female
2   26.4    22.5    Female
3   43.2    33.0    Male
4   22.5    21.8    Male
5   19.4    29.6    Male
6   20.5    34.6    Female
7   22.7    27.2    Female
8   17.5    15.5    Male
```

```
BMI_means = {}
for i in range(len(df)-1):    
    BMI_means[i] = (df.BMI[i] + df.BMI[i+1])/2
    
BMI_means
```

output:

```
{0: 16.75,
 1: 19.4,
 2: 27.75,
 3: 27.4,
 4: 25.700000000000003,
 5: 32.1,
 6: 30.9,
 7: 21.35}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is one way :

```
df['AVG'] = (df['BMI'] + df['BMI'].shift(-1)).div(2)
```

output:

```
    Age   BMI  Gender    AVG
0  23.0  17.2    Male  16.75
1  25.6  16.3  Female  19.40
2  26.4  22.5  Female  27.75
3  43.2  33.0    Male  27.40
4  22.5  21.8    Male  25.70
5  19.4  29.6    Male  32.10
6  20.5  34.6  Female  30.90
7  22.7  27.2  Female  21.35
8  17.5  15.5    Male    NaN
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @eshirvana; This is so neat, brief and faster (I think) compared to the looping.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

```
df["BMI"].rolling(2).mean().shift(-1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Chrysophylaxs. But, could you explain more on the `rolling` method. Is it like moving mean/average in Python?

Comment: Correct! You specifty a window size (=2), and pandas will "slide" a window of that size across your entire frame, one by one, which you might envision as lots of smaller dataframes with window size rows. It provides the `mean` method to determine the mean for each of the windows. Docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rolling.html